# Indexing into NSArray with JSON object

Tags: ios, swift

I receive an object that is sent as a pointer to a collection.
I can access the fields directly as an NSDictionary.

The `emails field` is sent as an array, and I receive it in parentheses.  Currently I get the `emailaddress` by what I feel is a roundabout method.
How can I most efficiently get to the email address?

```
let allDoc = users.allDocuments[0]
print("allDoc: \(allDoc)")

let emailsArray = users.allDocuments[0].valueForKey("emails") as! NSArray
print("emailsArray: \(emailsArray)")

let emailAddress = emailsArray[0]["address"] as! String
print("emailAddress: \(emailAddress)")
```

> Console output:

```
allDoc: <METDocument key: <collection: users, ID: kzzw3vcqukD62xEyz>, fields: {
    emails =     (
                {
            address = "xxxx@gmail.com";
            verified = 1;
        }
    );
    profile =     {
        address =         {
            city = "";
            country = nor;
            lineOne = "";
            lineTwo = "";
            zip = "";
        };
        card =         {
            last4 = 4242;
            verified = 1;
        };
        filledOut = 1;
        name =         {
            first = XXXX;
            last = XXXX;
        };
        phone = 9999999999;
        validated = 1;
    };
}>
emailsArray: (
        {
        address = "xxxx@gmail.com";
        verified = 1;
    }
)
emailAddress: xxxx@gmail.com
```

Comment: Update your question with the results of printing `users.allDocuments[0]`.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated

Comment: It is a Meteor-iOS object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the email address you could simply do:

```
let emailsAddress = users.allDocuments[0]["emails"][0][@"address"] as! String
print("emailAddress: \(emailAddress)")
```

But it really is better to use multiple lines. It makes the code much easier to read and debug. Also, putting all that onto one line doesn't allow any error checking. What if the `@"emails"` key has an empty array, for example? The code will crash.